# Javascript Array not pushing when having the same same value to object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object, push

objects ignores other array with same values. 
for example

```
data[2018][2][25] <-- this ones gets ignored to the object
data[2018][2][22]
```

Code:

```
var date = new Date();
var data = {};
<?php $eventsNum = 3>

<?php for ($r =1; $r <= 3; $r++):?>

    data[<?php echo $calendarYear[$r]?>] = {};
    <?php for ($s =1; $s <= 3; $s++):?>
        data[<?php echo $calendarYear[$r]?>][<?php echo $calendarMonth[$s]?>] = {};
        <?php for ($t =1; $t <= 2; $t++):?>
            data[<?php echo $calendarYear[$r]?>][<?php echo $calendarMonth[$s]?>][<?php echo $calendarDay[$s] ?>] = {};
            //$num =  $calendarDay[$s];
            try {
              data[<?php echo $calendarYear[$r]?>][<?php echo $calendarMonth[$s]?>][<?php echo $calendarDay[$s] ?>].push({
                    startTime: "<?php echo $calendarStart_time[1]?>",
                    endTime: "<?php echo $calendarEnd_time[1] ?>",
                    text: "<?php echo $calendar_description[1] ?>"
```

Comment: Your code ends in the middle of a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each time through the loops you completely replace the existing object in that property. Change:

```
data[<?php echo $calendarYear[$r]?>] = {};
```

to:

```
if (!data[<?php echo $calendarYear[$r]?>]) {
    data[<?php echo $calendarYear[$r]?>] = {};
}
```

and similarly for all the other initializations.